# CSS: Fix div position

Tags: html, css

I tried to fix **response** div position fixed:
HTML is:

```
<div id="response">
<table width="100%" cellspacing="5" style="background-image:url(images/bg.gif); background-repeat:no-repeat; width:100%;">
    <tr>
        <td class="clock" colspan="2"><?php include'scripts/clock.html'; ?></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
<div>
<img src="images/map.gif" border="0" usemap="#Msj_Map" alt="map" class="map" />
<map name="Msj_Map" id="Msj_Map">   
    <area id="8" shape="poly" coords="436,141,486,141,486,207,436,206" />
    <area id="1" shape="poly" coords="163,148,163,170,159,170" />
    <area id="2" shape="poly" coords="163,207,153,207,159,173,163,173" />
    <area id="189" shape="poly" coords="198,281,199,307,161,307,161,282" />
    <area id="190" shape="poly" coords="198,309,199,333,161,334,161,309" />
    <area id="165" shape="poly" coords="540,230,570,230,577,236,577,271,540,271" />
    <area id="40" shape="poly" coords="384,1156,419,1156,419,1180,383,1180" />
    <area id="39" shape="poly" coords="422,1156,458,1156,458,1180,422,1181" />
    <area id="54" shape="poly" coords="321,1109,353,1109,359,1116,360,1159,321,1159" />
    <area id="29" shape="poly" coords="356,1235,387,1235,387,1274,356,1274" />
    <area id="22" shape="poly" coords="390,1277,457,1277,457,1311,453,1315,390,1315" />
    <area id="23" shape="poly" coords="321,1277,387,1277,387,1315,321,1315" />
    <area id="24" shape="poly" coords="319,1277,319,1316,252,1316,252,1277" />
</map>
</div>
```

like http://www.noobcube.com/wp-content/uploads/demos/062709-fixed-header-footer/demo/
I used its logic but during implementation I found that `<map>` tag does not play its part with other elements because `<map>` draws just over an image and therefore does not support `overflow:scroll`. But `<map>` is the key element in my code.

May be there is some other solution to fix it.

Comment: Can't you just change `<map>` to a `<div>` ???

Comment: nop my friend, actually this map contains more than 200 polygons and i don't know to draw polygons using <div> :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long struggle i catch **z-index** and create css for **response** and `<map>` divs:

```
.calculator{
    z-index:1000;
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
}
.map-wrap{
    margin-top:350px;
}

<div id="response" class="calculator">
<table width="100%" cellspacing="5" style="background-image:url(images/bg.gif); background-repeat:no-repeat; width:100%;">
    <tr>
        <td class="clock" colspan="2"><?php include'scripts/clock.html'; ?></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
<div class="map-wrap">
<img src="images/map.gif" border="0" usemap="#Msj_Map" alt="map" class="map" />
<map name="Msj_Map" id="Msj_Map">   
    <area id="8" shape="poly" coords="436,141,486,141,486,207,436,206" />
    <area id="1" shape="poly" coords="163,148,163,170,159,170" />
    <area id="2" shape="poly" coords="163,207,153,207,159,173,163,173" />
    <area id="189" shape="poly" coords="198,281,199,307,161,307,161,282" />
    <area id="190" shape="poly" coords="198,309,199,333,161,334,161,309" />
    <area id="165" shape="poly" coords="540,230,570,230,577,236,577,271,540,271" />
    <area id="40" shape="poly" coords="384,1156,419,1156,419,1180,383,1180" />
    <area id="39" shape="poly" coords="422,1156,458,1156,458,1180,422,1181" />
    <area id="54" shape="poly" coords="321,1109,353,1109,359,1116,360,1159,321,1159" />
    <area id="29" shape="poly" coords="356,1235,387,1235,387,1274,356,1274" />
    <area id="22" shape="poly" coords="390,1277,457,1277,457,1311,453,1315,390,1315" />
    <area id="23" shape="poly" coords="321,1277,387,1277,387,1315,321,1315" />
    <area id="24" shape="poly" coords="319,1277,319,1316,252,1316,252,1277" />
</map>
</div>
```

and get rid of it. :)

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap a div around `<img>` and `<map>`. Like so :

```
<div class="map-wrap">
<img ... >
<map>
...
</map>
</div>
```

And add css :

```
.map-wrap {position:relative;}
```

For the other 2 answers `<map>` cannot be replaced by `<div>`

The `<map>` tag is used for defining an image map. Which is the image divided in to clickable areas or mouse sensitive areas.

Comment: thanks, but z-index the only attribute which i was missing.. !

Answer (score -1):

Better using a `<div>` instead `<map>`.
Tell in CSS that the `<div>` must have a fixed position and everything should works fine.